# Add and delete a random edge in networkx

Tags: python, random, graph, networkx

I'm using NetworkX in python. Given any undirected and unweighted graph, I want to loop through all the nodes. With each node, I want to add a random edge and/or delete an existing random edge for that node with probability p. Is there a simple way to do this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Delete a random existing edge is easier, I can make the existing neighbors of a node into a list and use random.choice to pick a node from it and delete that edge. However, adding a random nonexisting edge I still don't have a good way to do it.

Comment: To randomly add edges between nodes, you could iterate over the graph to get node _i_ and randomly select another node _j_ from the graph for which there is no edge between _i_ and _j_, then add an edge with probability _p_

Answer (score 12):

## Create a new random edge in networkx

Let's set up a test graph:

```
import networkx as nx
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

graph = nx.Graph()
graph.add_edges_from([(1,3), (3,5), (2,4)])
nx.draw(graph, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

[image: Figure 1]

Now we can pick a random edge from a list of non-edge from the graph. It is not totally clear yet what is the probability you mentioned. Since you add a comment stating that you want to use `random.choice` I'll stick to that.

```
def random_edge(graph, del_orig=True):
    '''
    Create a new random edge and delete one of its current edge if del_orig is True.
    :param graph: networkx graph
    :param del_orig: bool
    :return: networkx graph
    '''
    edges = list(graph.edges)
    nonedges = list(nx.non_edges(graph))

    # random edge choice
    chosen_edge = random.choice(edges)
    chosen_nonedge = random.choice([x for x in nonedges if chosen_edge[0] == x[0]])

    if del_orig:
        # delete chosen edge
        graph.remove_edge(chosen_edge[0], chosen_edge[1])
    # add new edge
    graph.add_edge(chosen_nonedge[0], chosen_nonedge[1])

    return graph
```

Usage exemple:

```
new_graph = random_edge(graph, del_orig=True)

nx.draw(new_graph, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

[image: Figure 2]

We can still add a probability distribution over the edges in `random.choice`if you need to (using `numpy.random.choice()` for instance).

Answer (score 2):

Given a node `i`, To add edges without duplication you need to know (1) what edges from `i` already exist and then compute (2) the set of candidate edges that don't exist from `i`.  For removals, you already defined a method in the comment - which is based simply on (1).
Here is a function that will provide one round of randomised addition and removal, based on list comprehensions

```py
def add_and_remove_edges(G, p_new_connection, p_remove_connection):    
    '''    
    for each node,    
      add a new connection to random other node, with prob p_new_connection,    
      remove a connection, with prob p_remove_connection    

    operates on G in-place    
    '''                
    new_edges = []    
    rem_edges = []    

    for node in G.nodes():    
        # find the other nodes this one is connected to    
        connected = [to for (fr, to) in G.edges(node)]    
        # and find the remainder of nodes, which are candidates for new edges   
        unconnected = [n for n in G.nodes() if not n in connected]    

        # probabilistically add a random edge    
        if len(unconnected): # only try if new edge is possible    
            if random.random() < p_new_connection:    
                new = random.choice(unconnected)    
                G.add_edge(node, new)    
                print "\tnew edge:\t {} -- {}".format(node, new)    
                new_edges.append( (node, new) )    
                # book-keeping, in case both add and remove done in same cycle  
                unconnected.remove(new)    
                connected.append(new)    

        # probabilistically remove a random edge    
        if len(connected): # only try if an edge exists to remove    
            if random.random() < p_remove_connection:    
                remove = random.choice(connected)    
                G.remove_edge(node, remove)    
                print "\tedge removed:\t {} -- {}".format(node, remove)    
                rem_edges.append( (node, remove) )    
                # book-keeping, in case lists are important later?    
                connected.remove(remove)    
                unconnected.append(remove)    
    return rem_edges, new_edges
```

To see this function in action:

```py
import networkx as nx
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

p_new_connection = 0.1
p_remove_connection = 0.1

G = nx.karate_club_graph() # sample graph (undirected, unweighted)
# show original
plt.figure(1); plt.clf()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,1, num=1, sharex=True, sharey=True)
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos, ax=ax[0])

# now apply one round of changes
rem_edges, new_edges = add_and_remove_edges(G, p_new_connection, p_remove_connection)

# and draw new version and highlight changes
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos, ax=ax[1])
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos=pos, ax=ax[1], edgelist=new_edges,
                       edge_color='b', width=4)
# note: to highlight edges that were removed, add them back in;
# This is obviously just for display!
G.add_edges_from(rem_edges)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos=pos, ax=ax[1], edgelist=rem_edges,
                       edge_color='r', style='dashed', width=4)
G.remove_edges_from(rem_edges)

plt.show()
```

And you should see something like this.
[image: example output]

Note that you could also do something similar with the adjacency matrix, 
`A = nx.adjacency_matrix(G).todense()` (it's a numpy matrix so operations like A[i,:].nonzero() would be relevant).  This might be more efficient if you have extremely large networks.